How to merge multiline grep output to a single line in linux
I have below output that have gathered by doing cat interim_detailed_cert | grep -E "Label :|dNSName:".
Output
Label : cert1
        dNSName: dns1.1
        dNSName: dns1.2
Label : cert2
        dNSName: dns2.1 
Label : cert3
        dNSName: dns3.1
        dNSName: dns3.2

From above, I'm trying to filter only the dNSName value, in a single line (if there are two values) separated by a comma ,
Expected output
dns1.1, dns1.2
dns2.2
dns3.1, dns3.2

Any suggestion on this will be helpful. Thanks

do these inputs and outputs really start with a dot in the first position, or do they start with a hyphen (as seen when the question is viewed in 'edit' mode), or do the raw lines have neither a dot nor a hyphen?

please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your coding attempt(s)

fwiw, once you bring awk into the mix there's rarely a need for grep; if you were to provide a sample of the raw input and your current grep -E call, it may be possible to provide an (awk) answer that removes the need for grep -E while also generating the desired output

The input doesnt start with a dot. It is just that I used to separate a namespace in the question.
Current grep -E command,
cat interim_detailed_cert | grep -E "Label :|dNSName:"

please update the formatting of the question so that it displays the actual output from the grep call; as currently formatted it looks like each line starts with a dot; alternatively, update the question with the contents of interim_detailed_cert and the grep call (not everyone is going to read through comments trying to piece together the entire picture)

Having formatting issues while pasting current output. Without dot, rest mentioned in the in the question will be the right one.

do the lines start with a hyphen?

No it doesnt start with a hyphen

@Raj87 Reference the Code and Preformatted Text" section of Markdown Help. Expand it to show more and use "code fences" around your grep output.

@Raj87 Or paste it as a gist and maybe we can help with the formatting.

Have edited the question. Does the format looks ok now?

format looks better, now; still need to see your coding attempt(s) and the (wrong) result(s) generated by your code; optionally: also provide raw contents of interim_detailed_cert

What if a label has no dNSName? Also, is this perhaps a YAML file?

For labels that does not have dNSNAME, should not return any value. Ideally, looking only for labels that has dNSNAME value. Yes, I'll add this logic to a YAML file using shell module.

@Raj87 If it's a YAML file, you should parse it as YAML. Trying to shortcut with grep risks mistakes.

The right solution won't be to parse the output of your grep command, it'll be to parse the contents of interim_detailed_cert so you should post that as your sample input so we can copy/paste it to test with.

This has the bones of a great question. However, if it is YAML, please post that. There are lots of tools that can parse that robustly.

Given your example I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let command output be
Label : cert1
        dNSName: dns1.1
        dNSName: dns1.2
Label : cert2
        dNSName: dns2.1 
Label : cert3
        dNSName: dns3.1
        dNSName: dns3.2

then
command | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n[^[:space:]]";OFS=", ";FPAT="dns[0-9.]+"}{$1=$1;print}'

gives output
dns1.1, dns1.2
dns2.1
dns3.1, dns3.2

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that records are separated by newline (\n) followed by non-white-space character, i.e. records are split at 1st character of every line which does not start with white-space character, that fields in output should be separated by comma followed by space, that fields are constituted by dns followed by one-or-more (+) digits or dots. I use $1=$1 to trigger string rebuilt and print to output line after change.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Thanks for your suggestion. It works well for above input data. However, while using it with my actual data, getting blank space (no output) instead. Can you please share for below input,
Label : test.nonprod.abcd.net
dNSName: FIRST.SIT.QMGR01
Label : check.nonprod.abcd.net
dNSName: SECOND.SIT.QMGR01
Label : blue.nonprod.abcd.net
dNSName: THIRD.PERF.QMGR01
dNSName: FOURTH.nonprod.ancd.net

@Raj87 you need to adjust FPAT for your input, please try FPAT="[A-Z.]+[0-9]+" and write if result is as desired

Using any awk and making assumptions about the contents of the input file based on the grep output you show from it in the question:
$ awk '
    /Label :/  { if (cnt++) print rec; rec=sep="" }
    /dNSName:/ { rec=rec sep $2; sep=", " }
    END { if (cnt) print rec }
' interim_detailed_cert
dns1.1, dns1.2
dns2.1
dns3.1, dns3.2

